# Need to replace the style attribute in my HTML code

Tags: html, styles

I just finished an assignment making a website with HTML for a class and just reread the instructions;

I can't use CSS or style attributes anywhere in my code but I've used style twice to center pictures. Since it only shows up 2 times I'm hoping it's an easy fix and I can resubmit.

This is the code I need to replace right now:

```
<div **style**="text-align: center;">
    <img src="picture.JPG" alt="caption" width="430" height="500" display="block" margin-left="auto" margin-right="auto">
</div>
```

The other instance of style is the same with a different picture.
Is there a way to center the pictures without using style or CSS?

Comment: Sorry, there's no way to move or position elements in the screen without CSS. Maybe using the deprecated tag `<center>`, but since it is deprecated, asking for someone to use it seems weird.

Comment: Could the instructions mean not to use inline styles?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you place the content inside a center tag such as `<center> This content is centered </center>`that should do the trick.

```
<center>
    <img src="picture.JPG" alt="caption" width="430" height="500" display="block" margin-left="auto" margin-right="auto">
</center>
```

Comment: `<center>` is obsolete and should not be used

Comment: <center> is indeed deprecated, but maybe Emily's instructor wants them to use it to keep up with her times.

Comment: this worked, thanks!

Comment: @Frenkey If the instructor is recommending using `<center>` they should be fired

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use just HTML (for whatever reason), use the `align` HTML attribute.

```
<p align="center">
 <img src"...">
</p>
```

Please just keep in mind that using CSS is much more appropriate for anything that has to do with styling. The code above should work as `align="center"` will (kind of) replicate the functionality of the CSS property `text-align`.

Comment: I'm sure CSS is better; I'm not sure why the assignment only wants HTML.

Comment: Like `<center>`, the `align` attribute is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: Sure, but it seems it's a requirement of the assignment to use just HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the margin `margin: 10px auto 20px; display: block;`
And if you need more reference to have a look at the following article.

https://html-online.com/articles/image-align-center/

Comment: I don't think that you've read the question, OP **can't** use CSS